# What's the meaning of "short the x"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

How should I understand "short the pound" in this sentence? My first guess would be "we all didn't need the pound anymore", though that sounds weird to me and I feel it's somehow not entirely correct. Another idea would be "to bring it down", "to cause it go down"?

> The pound was supposedly fixed at a high arbitrary level and a lot of us knew that we were all **short the pound**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more about economics, and a detailed description about currency is beyond this exchange, but essentially what it means to "short" a currency, is to take an investment position that is based upon the expectation that the value of that currency will *decrease*.

It's seen as a sign of lack of confidence in that currency (especially if you short the currency of your own nation). So you can see in context, there is a reference to a

> high arbitrary level

meaning that there was a feeling that the pound was *overvalued* and therefore the market would eventually correct, and lower the value of the pound, meaning they stood to make money by *shorting* the pound.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_(finance) for a good brief introduction

Comment: Also, you can "short" any kind of investment that changes in value.  It's easier to "short" things like currency, stocks, or durable goods -- anything that is traded on any kind of ["futures" exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_exchange).